# Don't loadOptions on initial render

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a ton of `select`s on my page and I don't want to fire off API calls for all of them every time the page loads. How can I skip `loadOptions` when async `react-select` components initialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, it looks like you can specify `autoload={false}`. From the [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select):

> Unless you specify the property autoload={false} the control will automatically load the default set of options (i.e. for input: '') when it is mounted.

---

Updated:

To get around the issue where you have to type something, you could add an `onFocus` callback. This will fire when the react-select component is clicked on or tabbed to, instead of waiting for the user to type something. It might look something like this:

```
<ReactSelect
  ...otherProps
  onFocus = { this.fetchData }
/>
```

To prevent constantly re-fetching the data, you might want to keep track of whether or not the data has been fetched in state somewhere. You could declare the initial state as `fetched: false`, then in the function that loads the options, set `this.setState({ fetched: true })`. Finally, your `fetchData` function can check `this.state.fetched` before requesting new data.

Comment: Darn, I really thought this was going to work. Unfortunately, now it doesn't show the options when you just click the select, but demands that you type some input before fetching options.

Comment: One way you can get around this is by forcing a fetch in the onFocus callback. Example code in the updated answer above.

Comment: Using onFocus is a good idea, but I can't get that callback triggered, nor onClick. It looks like other people are struggling with this too, it turns out: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1525. Something that's working, but seems ugly, is catching click events on the container div, finding the input with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelector('input')` and then blurring and focusing it. That causes a search to be triggered and show up in the drop down.

Comment: Good find! That is... annoying haha. Good luck with the project, hopefully the react-select folks fix that up soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
state= {option1:'', option2:'', option3:''}
```

If option 1 is filled out render select #2's values

`this.state.option1 && apicall for option 2().`

If option 2 is filled out render select #3's values

`this.state.option2 && apicall for option 3().`

All of this can be in `componentDidMount()`

This is assuming when the user selects a value you are storing that value in the state.